# Watch local variables

Tags: debugging, brightscript

I am using sublime editor for brightscripting and was wondering if there is any way that I could add watches and type in local expression in debug console. So that every time, I dont dump my code lods and lods of print statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can run code snippets in the [debug console](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Brightscript+Debug+Console) you telnet into. Break execution with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> or `STOP` statement, then type away.